# What should be the standard connection timeout and socket timeout in android

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have implemented the Rest calls in my app using the HttpClient. I see that on a slow connection my requests stay in execution state for a long time. And I want to cancel the http requests if it take a long time.
So, What should be the standard ConnectionTimeout and socket timeout in android app if json data is being fetched from java server.

Comment: The standard connect timeout is normally around a minute on all platforms I've used. The read timeout is infinite by default.

Answer (score 2):

This does less depend on the platform (Android) than on the use case. If your user needs the answer from the request to continue working, you might take a longer time, if it is just a background-update you can have less time, even if in this case the user will maybe not realize that he is waiting for something.

The main point is that the user should be informed that you are still doing something in background and should have the possibility to cancel the task if it takes too long. Unimportant background updates he probably does not want to see at all.

One of the best implementation IME seen is from Amazon who update the UI after some seconds stating the request takes longer. If still the request fails, you are  notified to try later and you can always cancel and go back.

Comment: Yeh! But atleast connection timeout could be set and same for all type of requests. What should it be then

Comment: in many cases it would be 10 seconds, but if the information is important and the user would be prepared to wait, a higher limit might be appropriate. Starting a new request after 10 seconds might also get a better user experience